# PHP-7.0 SSH2 Module does work in command line but not on website

Tags: php, libssh2, ssh2

I want to install SSH2 on my Server and I did it via PECL. I used PECL because I want ssh2 version 1.2 and not the default apt version which is 0.12. Unfortunately, I somehow can't use it

I have following file:

test.php

```
<?php var_dump(function_exists("ssh2_disconnect")); ?>
```

When I execute `PHP test.php` I get `true`. When I execute it via my browser, I get `false`.

Why does it get loaded in the PHP command line but not in PHP browser (I am using Apache2 with keyhelp)

Comment: Think about this: Why *do* modules get loaded? BTW: Upgrade PHP, 7.0 is as maintained as 5.6, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: its not a problem that's ssh2 specific, i tried to install seaslog and it also only shows up in command line mode and not fpm mode